# What is the safest method for increasing the build limit in settlements?

Tags: fallout-4

I have seen three ways to circumvent the building limit for settlements. Those being the "scrap weapon on ground" exploit, console commands, and a mod. Is there a "best" one? As in, does one hinder performance/stability/etc. the least?

Comment: It's worth noting that, on console platforms (XBox One & PS4), the "scrap an item on the group" method is your *only* option.

Comment: I'm kind of curious what has led to you reaching the build limit. That's a lot of building.

Comment: DCShannon, honestly I have a lot of trouble staying within the build limit at several settlements. The most recent culprit being the Castle as I've begun trying to fill it in. So far I have very little to show for it, especially due to my frequent shortage of wood.

Comment: @DCShannon - I can second the comment about the castle. As there is already loads of pre-built "stuff" it is quite easy to push the limit early on. Even when you first unlock the castle, I'm pretty sure that meter is 1/3 of the way filled.

Comment: I'm on the Xbox, so I've used the drop/store weapons method extensively, at just about every settlement (I really enjoy settlement building). I haven't run into any issues except for one settlement that is buggy in general (it has 51 settlers, and I have no idea why). The issue I have there is my turrets occasionally disappear. But loading a save or leaving and returning seem to remedy that problem.

Answer (score 2):

[As mentioned here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/244006/52800):

> The size budget is a polygon count designed to keep your frame rate steady by preventing you from building massive and overly complicated settlements. The size limit and current size used are actually attributes against the workbench in the settlement itself and differ between settlements.
>
> This is calculated based on the number of objects in the settlement in combination with the size and complexity of the objects. More complex objects have a higher polygon count and as such use more of the budget. Scrap contributes to this limit so you could "fill" a settlement and then go around destroying all of the broken beds, cups, chairs, etc and have more budget available to build more.

This means that the performance hit is caused by drawing an additional quantity of items - all methods that "increase" the maximum number of objects you can build in your settlement will have a hit on performance because your machine has to draw more objects. The amount of performance hit you experience will be down to the platform you're playing on and how well the game was optimized on that platform or the specification of your hardware (PC), rather than the method you use to increase the value of a couple of variables in game.