# Fallout 4 Settlement loosing its resources

Tags: fallout-4

Just got back to one of my settlements (Starlight Drive-In) where at first everything is normal

- Water is at 220
- Food is at 108
- Power is at 250
- Defense is at 447

After about 1 minute in the settlement, all the ratings go down. Both my fusion generators just destroyed themselves in front of me. Then, half of my food supply goes with the mutfruit plants destroyed out of nowhere and my water purifiers get destroyed.

No there was no early warning notification saying "defend starlight drive in" or "starlight drive in is under attack", and no enemies appeared.

I'm wondering if someone could tell me why my settlement decides to randomly destroy itself without an attack even when I'm in said settlement when it happens.

Comment: What platform is this? PC or Console?

Comment: Given there is no river in that settlement, 220 water is something like 70+ water pumps.  108 food is 108 Mut Fruit plant at minimum.  447 Defense is a LOT of turrets...

You probably build too many things in that settlement and the area glitched up, destroying everything.

Comment: For the water purifiers there is a small pond in the middle I managed to fit 1 industrial and 3 purifiers and a lot of 10 unit water electrical pumps.  Yeah I did go over the settlement limit using the drop items and store method which of course causes I guess a frame rate lag. Instead I loaded a previous save and it fine well for now ill try and scrap some of the purifiers. Also for the platform I play on is console Xbox One so not the best thing to use when trying to go over the limit. @Nelson

Comment: There are a lot of random pre-built things in that settlement.  Did you go around and clear as many things as you can?  You can scrap the radioactive barrels in the tiny pond in the settlement build menu to remove the dangerous radiation.  Try to clear out as many entities as possible in the area.

Comment: You also need to lower the amount of turrets.  You don't need to build so many.  The absolute best way to build turrets, in any settlement, is to build a bunch of stairs, something like 3 long stair's worth, build a square platform, and put something like a dozen turrets in the sky, then you remove the platform and stairs.  You end up with a cluster of turrets high in the sky that can spot the whole settlement.  Just a bunch of heavy machine gun turrets is enough to take out Ancient Deathclaws.

Answer (score 1):

As Nelson mentioned in a comment, you have most likely built too many buildings/crafted items in that settlement. Unless you're on PC and are running a few mods, settlements have a capped size in which to place buildings/crafts.

[Take a look at this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244001/what-contributes-to-the-settlement-size-limit) to get some more information on how size is calculated in a settlement. Most likely your buildings/crafts were destroyed in order to lower the settlement size.